# Playing only audio from an HLS video stream when not connected to WiFi using Daily Motion's hls.js

Tags: dailymotion-api

This question is in regards to DailyMotion's hls.js API

My goal is to save on data usage when not connected to WiFi by playing only the audio portion of a HLS video stream.

I have looked at similar questions for other APIs but have not found anything relevant to the hls.js API.

**Details**:
I tested my live stream HLS file on your demo page. It identified 1 audio track and displayed it in the Audio Track Controls. At the bottom of this post I am including the format of my HLS file with identifying info changed.

**Question**:
Will the hsl.js API allow me to force the playback to only audio once I have identified the lack of a WiFi connection? What setting or command would I use to do that? Alternatively, can I force playback to the lowest resolution?

Thanks,
RKern

**HLS File Format**:

```
    #EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-VERSION:5
    #EXT-UPLYNK-LIVE
    #EXT-X-START:TIME-OFFSET=0.00
    #EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
    #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",NAME="unspecified",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
    #UPLYNK-MEDIA0:416x234x30,baseline-13,2x48000
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,RESOLUTION=416x234,BANDWIDTH=471244,CODECS="mp4a.40.5,avc1.42000d",FRAME-RATE=30.000,AUDIO="aac",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=411975
    http://content-ause1.uplynk.com/channel/test/d.m3u8?pbs=test
    #UPLYNK-MEDIA0:704x396x30,main-30,2x48000
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,RESOLUTION=704x396,BANDWIDTH=873267,CODECS="mp4a.40.5,avc1.4d001e",FRAME-RATE=30.000,AUDIO="aac",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=688830
    http://content-ause1.uplynk.com/channel/test/e.m3u8?pbs=test
    #UPLYNK-MEDIA0:896x504x30,main-31,2x48000
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,RESOLUTION=896x504,BANDWIDTH=1554841,CODECS="mp4a.40.5,avc1.4d001f",FRAME-RATE=30.000,AUDIO="aac",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1171051
    http://content-ause1.uplynk.com/channel/test/f.m3u8?pbs=test
    #UPLYNK-MEDIA0:1280x720x30,main-31,2x48000
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,RESOLUTION=1280x720,BANDWIDTH=3328000,CODECS="mp4a.40.5,avc1.4d001f",FRAME-RATE=30.000,AUDIO="aac",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2414865
    http://content-ause1.uplynk.com/channel/test/g.m3u8?pbs=test
    #UPLYNK-MEDIA0:192x108x15,baseline-11,2x48000
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,RESOLUTION=192x108,BANDWIDTH=136226,CODECS="mp4a.40.5,avc1.42000b",FRAME-RATE=15.000,AUDIO="aac",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=120009
    http://content-ause1.uplynk.com/channel/test/b.m3u8?pbs=test
    #UPLYNK-MEDIA0:256x144x30,baseline-12,2x48000
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,RESOLUTION=256x144,BANDWIDTH=259601,CODECS="mp4a.40.5,avc1.42000c",FRAME-RATE=30.000,AUDIO="aac",AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=232565
    http://content-ause1.uplynk.com/channel/test/c.m3u8?pbs=test
```